# How to attach a link to a shape or text box on Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-apps-script-addon, google-slides

I know how to add a shape to a slide, but I know in Google Slides you are able to link another slide to display once you click on that text box. Is it possible to in App Script create a shape and then attach a link to it?

I have looked at the API documentation and was confused as to if it was possible.

This is a Sheets/Slides Add-On.

What I need to do is when a button is pressed on my Add On menu that I created, is to create a Slide in Google Slides, and use the information from a Sheets. I want to create a TextBox, and have when you click it link to another slide in the Slide Show. I just want it all automated.

If it is possible, how do I apply it to a shape I created?

```
var elementId = 'MyTextBox_001';
  var pt350 = {
    magnitude: 350,
    unit: 'PT'
  };
  var requests = [{
    createShape: {
      objectId: elementId,
      // tried linkUrl: "link";
      shapeType: 'TEXT_BOX',
      elementProperties: {
        pageObjectId: "slide_001_001",

        size: {
          height: pt350,
          width: pt350
        },
        transform: {
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
          translateX: 350,
          translateY: 100,
          unit: 'PT'
        }
      }
    }
  },

// Insert text into the box, using the supplied element ID.
{
   insertText: {
     objectId: elementId,
     // tried linkUrl: "link";
     insertionIndex: 0,
     text: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,2).getValue()
    }
 }];

// have tried elementId.setLinkUrl(linkHere);
```

Comment: The code isn't complete and the question hasn't enough details. You are using a project bounded to a spreadsheet, right? Which the shape to add the link? What did you tried so far?

Comment: ! ! ! ! ! ! ! See - Star - Comment in Issue tracker! ! ! ! ! ! !    
"Page elements on Slides should be selectable to run scripts like the shapes and images in spreadsheet"   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186214943

"Presentation mode in slides should fill window not device"  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186204484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a slide, add a shape and add a link to it using the following code:

```js
  var presentationId =  "<YOUR_PRESENTATION_ID>";
  var newSlideId = Utilities.getUuid();
  var newElementId = Utilities.getUuid();
  var pt350 = {
    magnitude: 350,
    unit: 'PT'
  };
  var requests = [
    {
      createSlide: {
        objectId: newSlideId
      }
    },
    {
      createShape: {
        objectId: newElementId,
        shapeType: 'TEXT_BOX',
        elementProperties: {
          pageObjectId: newSlideId,
          size: {
            height: pt350,
            width: pt350
          },
          transform: {
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1,
            translateX: 350,
            translateY: 100,
            unit: 'PT'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      insertText: {
        objectId: newElementId,
        insertionIndex: 0,
        text: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,2).getValue()
      }
    },
    {
      updateShapeProperties: {
        objectId: newElementId,
        shapeProperties: {
          link: {
            pageObjectId: "<YOUR_PAGE_ID>"
          }
        },
        fields: "link"
      }
    }];
```

Note that you will need your presentation's id and the destination page's id. If you prefer, you can use a slide index as a destination ([more information here](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.Link)).

In case you need more help creating a slides add-on, you can visit [this example](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/slides/quickstart/translate).

If you have any other question regarding this topic, please don't hesitate to reach back.

Regards

Comment: you beautiful soul. You're kind of amazing ngl.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Checkout  [Extending Google Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides) and [shape.setLinkUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#setlinkurlurl)

Comment: I clicked on the link(s) and it put me in the right direction, but I can't figure out how to apply it to the shape I created. Should I create a new question?

Comment: Pythonnnnnn: Check my answer, it may provide you the insight you need.

Comment: @carlesgg97 it did! Also Ruben, thank you! You put me on the right track to understand it. I appreciate both of you!